# how to create a spiral bar chart using ECharts

Tags: echarts

I want to create spiral bar chart using apache echarts like this chart
[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVcPy.png) [sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p3Af.jpg) [sample 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRPVd.jpg)

Comment: What did you try ? Can you give us some piece of code and data please

Comment: thanks for replying @FBlanchet and sorry for the delay in response because i forgot that i made question here for this. i have been creating long list of charts. its one of them. as far i created charts using echarts, i encountered coordinate system like cartesian2d, polar,geo,... this spiral bar not fitting in one but two cartesian and polar, but i didn't see any option to fuse both. honestly i didn't tried for this one yet. before that wanted to get some insights from experienced ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's bar chart with polar coordinates: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-polar-real-estate — official example.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply @SergeyFedorov , i too saw that chart that site. i made mistake that didn't gave clear image previously, now i have updated the question with more sample. please take a look at that. sorry for delayed response

Comment: i don't understand what you want. `Polar bar` is ready to use, I was published link above.  What for to fuse both coordinates system? I taken look on example pictures, the is different: #1 and #3 is similar but #2 is dramatically different. You need to provide detail info or source code where you tried to build desired form.

Comment: in cartesian2d we will have x axis and y axis, in polar we have radius axis and angle axis ,now if you see #3 image, x axis starting from center and go along circular path outside. it can be done using polar bar chart with a workaround given in official example. but in the same way i need to plot #2 which is horizontal bar. , what i meant about fuse is cartesian2d system visualized as involute curve. if i am confusing, check this from amcharts [link](https://codepen.io/tdkdhilip/pen/QWNjgqG)

Comment: [sample1&2](https://codepen.io/tdkdhilip/pen/KKzdqZW)

Comment: I think I understand. Need lot of time to spend for to get what you want, I not have it right now. Maybe later. It's definitely will be drawn with custom series because the current series even polar coordinates not adapted for spiral. You can try to imitate it with generate data so that the result was similar to the [spiral](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xBkj8rXsAl) or use [radar series](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=radar).

Comment: I also felt the same. that's y came here to know if anyone else tried it before,if so I can get any guidance. anyways thank you. will post if I create.